# how to match string in double quotes in kotlin by regex

Tags: regex, kotlin

---

I want to find string that's inside double quotes.

```
text : <a href = "http://weqweqwewqewqeqwe">

expected : http://weqweqwewqewqeqwe
```

how to get string using regex.

```
val page1 = "<a href=\"http://weqweqwewqewqeqwe\">"
val urlMatcher = "\".+\"".toRegex()
println(page1.split(urlMatcher))
```

above code is my thinking. but, It is not working well.

Comment: Please tag your question with the language.

Comment: sorry, now added tag

Comment: Why using `text.split()`.Try `urlMatcher.find(text)`

Comment: *It is not working well* isn't an informative statement. Please show us what you get from that lines of code.

Comment: maybe you rather want a parser instead e.g. something like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use parenthesis to group a certain part of regex matched text:

```
val urlMatcher = "\"(.+)\"".toRegex()
```

And then use [`find`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find.html) to extract text matching your regex from a string like so:

```
urlMatcher.find(text)?.groupValues?.getOrNull(1)
```

Comment: but, I want to find string that's inside double quotes, so I used urlMatcher.find(text)?.groupValues?.getOrNull(0) statement.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
val page1 = "<a href=\"http://weqweqwewqewqeqwe\">"
val urlMatcher = "\"([^\"]*)\"".toRegex()
// Or, you may reduce escaping with a triple-quoted string literal:
// val urlMatcher = """"([^"]*)"""".toRegex()
println(urlMatcher.find(page1)?.value)  // => "http://weqweqwewqewqeqwe"
println(urlMatcher.find(page1)?.groupValues?.getOrNull(1)) // => http://weqweqwewqewqeqwe
```

See the [Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/HBY96805). Note the `Regex#find(String)` syntax. After you get a match, `.value` will fetch you the whole match value (no need of `.groupValues?.getOrNull(0)`) and `.groupValues?.getOrNull(1)` will fetch the value inside Group 1.

The `"([^"]*)"` pattern matches a `"`, then  captures 1 or more chars other than `"` into Group 1 (with `[^"]*`) and then matches the closing double quotation mark.

Whenever you need to match a `"..."` substring that may contain **escaped double quotes** use

```
val urlMatcher = """(?s)(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*("[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")""".toRegex()
```

To capture just the substring between double quotes move the capturing parentheses as shown below:

```
"""(?s)(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*"(([^\\"]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*))""""
                         ^                        ^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zb9oNQ/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(?s)` - a `.` now matches any char
- `(?<!\\)` - no `\` char can be present immediately to the left of the current position
- `(?:\\{2})*` - 0 or more sequences of double backslashes (thus, all escaped quotes will get ignored)
- `"`  - a double quote
- `([^\\"]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^\\"]*` - 0+ chars other than `\` and `"`
  - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - 0+ occurrences of

    - `\\.` - a `\` followed with any char
    - `[^\\"]*` - 0+ chars other than `\` and `"`
- `"` - a double quote.